# How would you set the NgPattern of an Angular NgMessages Application for two given years as a date range

Tags: angularjs, regex, date, ng-messages, ng-pattern

I have a date field like:

```
input(name='date', type='date', ng-pattern='/^[1900-2016]$/', ng-model='dateModel')
```

How do you set the ng-pattern for two given dates a date range. For example: only years from 1900 - 2016 are allowed? Keep in mind that we get a date format which basically looks like: 1900-01-01T....

I have two variables: dateRangeFrom, dateRangeTo. Is it somehow possible to use them for the pattern? Because I wanna use this pattern multiple times and the dateRangeTo should be the current year.

Comment: `/^19[0-9]{2}|20[0-1][0-6]$/` will match between 1900 and 2016.

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne so, you cannot enter 2008?

Comment: I only want the specific range to be possible. 20160000 would be possible as well.

Comment: Well, I guess `/^(19[0-9]{2}|20(0[0-9]|1[0-6]))/` should do if only the first digits are to be checked.

Comment: I suck at regex, apparently.

Comment: *Is it possible to use them like: [dateRangeFrom - dateRangeTo]?* - NO, that is not possible.